# Export cosmosDB by an azure function and save the file in a blob storage

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to backup a cosmos DB by using an azure function and save the .JSON file in a Azure blob storage

Comment: This question is a bit too open-ended. What have you tried so far and what's your issue now?

Comment: My backup strategy is running with a scheduled task in a local machine,  i'd like to replaced with a azure function and blob storage and if possible, how can be done.

Comment: Yes there is an option to do it that way. But please start by putting in some effort. There is [plenty of good docs available](https://www.google.nl/search?q=azure+scheduled+function&ie=&oe=).

Comment: @giantLincecum Hi,any updates now?

Comment: Hey @JayGong thanks for your suggestion, sounds like a good solution, I'll try them out.

Comment: @giantLincecum Sure,waiting for you reply.

Comment: @giantLincecum Hi,does my answers helps you?

Comment: Hello @JayGong it was easier with Azrue Data Factory !, thanks a lot !

Comment: @giantLincecum You're welcome,you could vote and mark my answer for others' reference, thank you.

Comment: @giantLincecum Hi,any progress now?

Comment: @giantLincecum Hi,no matter how many reputations you have, you can mark answer if you adopt it. Besides, you can vote now.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure , you can create a `Time-Trigger` Azure Function to run your backup job. Just use [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet) to get the data from your cosmos db and save them as files into blob storage.

Another choice is [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal).

***Cosmos DB Output:***

[image]

***Blob Storage Input:***

[image]

***Backup pipeline:***

[image]

***Result:***

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

check out **Azure Data Factory**.  I think it's pretty good and easy to use it for backup functionality.